# connect Postgres database in docker to app in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm new with Kubernetes and I try to understand how to connect Postgres database which is outside from  Kubernetes (exactly in docker with ip address 172.17.0.2 and port 5432) to my webapp in Kubernetes.

I try connect database through env variable `PS_DATABASE_URL` in Deployment section.

But it cannot find mentioned url for postgres. How it need to be done correctly?

`webapp.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: dmitriy83/flask_kuber
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: PS_DATABASE_URL
            value: postgresql://postgres:password@172.17.0.2:5432/db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30100
```

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, where your k8s infra is hosted? Minikube, cloud?

Comment: Can you move the database into Kubernetes too?  If not, "in Docker" isn't really a meaningful place for the database to be running; the Kubernetes cluster would probably need to connect to a published port on the host running the container, the same as any other out-of-cluster resource.

Comment: can you check is the k8s master has the connectivity of ip and port of database, there might be some firewall issue

Comment: @jabbson in Minikube

Comment: @DavidMaze i understand that Docker not the best place for db. Ii need to know how to connect external db which is not in Kubernetes to app in Kubernetes

Comment: @Hackaholic I do not understand how to check it, could you please provide example?

Comment: you can use telnet or nc example: `telnet <ip> <port>`

Comment: @Hackaholic Have you managed to have this work? If not, what issues do you have?

Comment: @Hackaholic, yes I made it workable (create external service)

Comment: @Dmitriy_kzn Previously mentioned not you... Great, you can then [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it, so it can be useful for other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. it depends from cloud provider. For this example i use amazon cloud and to connect database on amazon (this is external service). So we must define it in yaml file like an external service.

`postgres_external.yaml`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: db.cdmhjidhpqyu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

to connect to external service you need to link to it on deployment.

`webapp.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: dmitriy83/flask_kuber
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
          - name: PS_DATABASE_URL
            value: postgresql://<username>:<password>@postgres:5432/db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30100
```

Please note in webapp.yaml, env section value `value: postgresql://<username>:<password>@postgres:5432/db`   contains **postgres** - this is name of our external service which we define in `postgres_external.yaml`